# Prepopulating a value in NewForm.aspx

Tags: jquery, spservices

I am sending a query string into NewForm.aspx.  I have populated a drop down with that value.  Everything works great in Chrome but Internet Explorer does not save the pre-populated value.  The value is actually populated on the dropdown list but if I click save, IE acts as if no option was selected. The values I expect do show up in the console.  What can I do to make IE recognize that a value has been selected?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
var supplierID = queryStringVals["SupplierID"];
console.log(supplierID);

$().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
    columnName: "SupplierID",
});

//like :contains but only selects exact matches
$.expr[':'].textEquals = function(a, i, m) {
    return $(a).text().match("^" + m[3] + "$");
};

var selectedSupplierID = $("option:textEquals('" + supplierID + "')").val();
$("select[title=SupplierID]").val(selectedSupplierID);

//No change
//$("select[title=SupplierID]").val(selectedSupplierID).trigger("click");

console.log($("select[title=SupplierID]").val());

//Nope, sigh
//$("option:contains('" + supplierID + "')").attr("selected", "selected");


//tried this before SPComplexToSimpleDropdown
//$("option:textEquals('" + supplierID + "')").val().next("img").trigger("click");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add this line to the end:

```
$("select[title=SupplierID]").change();
```

Full code is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
        var supplierID = queryStringVals["SupplierID"];

        $().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
            columnName: "SupplierID",
        });

        //like :contains but only selects exact matches
        $.expr[':'].textEquals = function(a, i, m) {
            return $(a).text().match("^" + m[3] + "$");
        };

        var selectedSupplierID = $("option:textEquals('" + supplierID + "')").val();
        $("select[title=SupplierID]").val(selectedSupplierID);
        $("select[title=SupplierID]").change(); 

    });
```